# Is there a way for me to recover my PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding, binary

I am coding using Visual Studio Code and my PHP file is now corrupted and I am missing 70% of the code. When I try to open it it says "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding". When I do open it, there are ? symbols where the code is supposed to be. I have tried opening it with different text editors and its the same. Is there any way I can fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Restore from backups or source control

Comment: PHP files are normally plain text, it sounds like you did something to overwrite it with the output of running it or copied over it with something else.  No, it is gone.  This is one way to learn that backups and version control are important.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly, plain text file will not show messages like that.
If it's overwrited, it colud probably not to fix.
(if it can, it'll also be diffcult.)

So you might need to learn that how to use `git`. (like `github`)